# simple mod_rewrite problem

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^?(.*) productfilter.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

---

This rewrite is returning : 
category=productfilter.php

can someone point out what I am doing wrong here

Comment: What did you want to happen instead?  I _think_ I know, but I shouldn't assume.

Comment: ah, thanks for asking andrew :o) - url.com/household/ category=household

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood, the issue is that the rewritten URL is getting re-rewritten.  Rewrite directives, at least in .htaccess context, get re-executed after a URL rewrite.  I think what you are trying to accomplish can be done with:

```
RewriteRule ^productfilter.php - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ productfilter.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

The first RewriteRule just declines to rewrite when productfilter.php already starts the path.